# Pointers and reference operator (&)

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm learning C++ and I have found this on a book:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int Age = 30;
int* pInteger = &Age; // pointer to an int, initialized to &Age

// Displaying the value of pointer
cout << “Integer Age is at: 0x” << hex << pInteger << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The book said that the output is the address in memory where Age is stored.

But the book doesn't talk about this:

```
*pInteger = &Age;
 pInteger = &Age;
```

**What is the difference between these two assignments?**

Comment: The `&` symbol when used with a type, declares a reference.  When used with a variable, returns the address or location of the variable.  Example: `int & ` -- declare a reference; "&Age" -- return location of `Age`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confused by this line

```
int* pInteger = &Age; // pointer to an int, initialized to &Age
```

The `*` symbol here is declaring pInteger as a pointer to an int. This is initialised (not assigned) to the address of Age which is permitted because Age is an int.

You could type

```
*pInteger = 45;
```

and that would be assigning to the integer to which pInteger points.

You can also type

```
int y = 35; 
pInteger = &y;
```

which would be reassigning the pointer to point to a different place.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be easier to understand if you break this

```
 int* pInteger = &Age;
```

down into two steps

```
 int* pInteger;
```

delares a variable of type pointer to int, and then

```
 pInteger = &Age;
```

assign the address of Age to pInteger, so pInteger now points to a specific integer.

If you wrote

```
 *pInteger = 95;
```

you would assign a new value to whatever pInteger is currently pointing to.

When you write

```
 int* pInteger = &Age;
```

you are declaring the variable and giving it an initial value, so that's not the same as the apparently similar

```
  *pInteger = &Age;
```

which is using pInteger but not declaring it so here you get the address of Age and are effectively attempting to assign that to the thing which pInteger points to, assigning an address to an int not being a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

`int* pInteger = &Age;` is not an assignment, but an initialization. Here, `*` is part of the type - `int*`, not to the integer `*pInteger`, like below.

The two you ask about are assignments:

```
*pInteger = &Age;
 pInteger = &Age;
```

The difference is that the first is illegal, the second is OK. That's because `&Age` has type `int*`, whereas `*pInteger` has type `int`, and it's illegal to assign an `int*` to an `int`. `pInteger`, however, has type `int*`, so the assignment is OK.

Answer (score 1):

`pInteger` is a pointer to int, and it is *initialized* to the address of `Age` in the first case (assuming you meant **`int`**`*pInteger = &Age;`), and *assigned* in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

First we declare and initialize a variable of type `int*`

```
      int*     pInteger   =          &Age;
//| var type | var name |   | value of type "int*"  |
```

Next we try to use assignment:

```
          pInteger       =         &Age;
//| var of type "int*" |   | value of type "int*"  |
         *pInteger      =         &Age;
//| var of type "int" |   | value of type "int*"  |
```

The last is incorrect until we cast `int*` to `int` (If our goal is to use adress like integer value). Unary operator dereference operator `*` means that we need something located at specified adress.